# What does this Bootstrap 4 class mean?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using a prebuilt bootstrap 4 theme for this site im working on. However, I've never seen this class before and I have searched the bs4 docs and can't seem to find it any where. The class is "g-py" and looks like this

```
<section id="priceCompare" class="g-py-90">
```

What does the g-py resemble? Whatever it is, it's causing the section below it to add more top padding to it than what should be there.

Comment: It's not from Bootstrap, it's from your theme. It's similar to the [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/), e.g. `.p-3` but not built-in

Comment: I don't think this is a Bootstrap class; I've found a couple results for random CSS frameworks for `px-*` and `py-*`, which I think translates to `padding x` (Horizontal) or `padding y` (Vertical)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It's just weird how all the other sections are using the same class and this one using the class keeps adding extra whitespace below it and I can't seem to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Bootstrap 4 class by that name. At the very least, if you're unable to find it within your default theme, you should be able to assume it's not Bootstrap.